# How to give a table an alias name only once in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say i have the following query.

```
SELECT a.num Num ,   a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM tbl_1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_2 b USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_3 c USING (num)
UNION
SELECT b.num Num , a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM tbl_2 b
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_1 a USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_3 c USING (num)
UNION
SELECT c.num Num , a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM tbl_3 c
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_1 a USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_2 b USING (num)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0593f/12/0
The problem is that instead of the table names tbl_1, tbl_2 and tbl_3 I have inner SELECT querys, for example:

```
FROM (SELECT...) a
```

I would like to write the table names(tbl_1, tbl_2, tbl_3) only once so i would not have to rewrite my inner SELECT querys many times.
I tried doing something like this but it gave me a sytax error:

```
SELECT a.num Num ,   a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM (SELECT...) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN c USING (num)
UNION
SELECT b.num Num , a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM (SELECT...) b
LEFT OUTER JOIN a USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN c USING (num)
UNION
SELECT c.num Num , a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM (SELECT...) c
LEFT OUTER JOIN a USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN b USING (num)
```

But when i write the code like this it works.

```
SELECT a.num Num ,   a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM (SELECT...) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT...) b USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT...) c USING (num)
UNION
SELECT b.num Num , a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM (SELECT...) b
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT...) a USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT...) c USING (num)
UNION
SELECT c.num Num , a.info infoA,
     b.info infoB,
     c.info infoC
FROM (SELECT...) c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT...) a USING (num)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT...) b USING (num)
```

Comment: A CTE? BTW, unrelated, why not UNION ALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that this will work in any form.
The separate queries are just combined by the UNION operator

I would recommend the usage of three different views for your specific problem.
Given you can create views on the database.

Comment: ya the best solution i found was to create temporary tables for the given inner querys

Comment: Temporary tables is also a nice approach. If you are using them very often create views, if not just create the temporary tables and let them be dropped at session end.

Answer (score 0):

Check this it will work

```
select sub.num Num , sub.info infoA, sub.info infoB, sub.info infoC 
from (

 SELECT a.num ,   a.info , b.info , c.info 
 FROM tbl_1 a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_2 b USING (num)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_3 c USING (num)
 UNION
 SELECT b.num , a.info , b.info , c.info 
 FROM tbl_2 b
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_1 a USING (num)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_3 c USING (num)
 UNION
 SELECT c.num  , a.info , b.info , c.info 
 FROM tbl_3 c
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_1 a USING (num)
 LEFT  OUTER JOIN tbl_2 b USING (num) )sub
```